# I want to make a stream of small data by calling it again and again

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

I have a question, I've got a small CSV data that I'm able to launch on flink with help of kafka . My question is can I call the same data, again and again, using window and trigger, or it'll call my data only once?

```
1,35
2,45
3,55
4,65
5,555
```

This is the data that I want to call again and again. Though I myself don't think so it's better to take 2nd opinion as I'm a beginner. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by call data again and again. But you can create a stream of that data in Flink using SourceFunction. For example, the following source creates a stream of that csv file and emits it every second.

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

DataStream<String> csvStream = env.addSource(new SourceFunction<String>() {
    @Override
    public void run(SourceContext<String> sourceContext) throws Exception {
        String data = "1,35\n" +
                "2,45\n" +
                "3,55\n" +
                "4,65\n" +
                "5,555";

        while(true) {
            sourceContext.collect(data);
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void cancel() {

    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks alot , this is what I was asking for, but can you add a scala snippet only if that won't bother you. Thanks though

Comment: Sorry, not really familiar with Scala